# How to complete my file processing program?

Tags: java

Hi I'm pretty new to java and I'm not sure how to complete my code.  I'm trying to write a program that reads a .txt file and fixes any spacing issues within the text.  I have written a code that places a space between each word, but I'm not sure how to get it to place two spaces after a ., !, or ?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Word_Processor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Programming3_text.txt"));
        PrintStream output =
            new PrintStream(new File("Programming3_text_fixed.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String text = input.nextLine();
            echoFixed(text, output);
            echoFixed(text, System.out);
        }
    }
    public static void echoFixed(String text, PrintStream output)
    {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
        if (data.hasNext())
        {
            output.print(data.next());
            while (data.hasNext())
            {
                output.print(" " + data.next());
            }
        }
        output.println();
    }
}
```

I tried adding IF statements but that would not work.  Like I said I'm a novice to Java and programming so any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Not sure what you mean by "that would not work"? The punctuation marks you  mention are a special case, and `if` is good at special cases. How would you determine if the punctuation was present. If it's present do one extra thing...

Answer (score 0):

Better go with StringTokenizer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Word_Processor {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Programming3_text.txt"));
        PrintStream output
                = new PrintStream(new File("Programming3_text_fixed.txt"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String text = input.nextLine();
            echoFixed(text, output);
            echoFixed(text, System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void echoFixed(String text, PrintStream output) {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text, " .,!?");//put the replaceable characters here DON'T FORGET ' '(space) THERE IS ONE JUST AT THE START OF " .,!?" BEFORE '.'
        String outputLine="";
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            outputLine = outputLine + tokenizer.nextToken() + " ";
        }
        output.println(outputLine.trim());
        /* Previous Code
         if (data.hasNext()) {
         output.print(data.next());
         while (data.hasNext()) {
         output.print(" " + data.next());
         }
         }
         output.println();*/
    }
}
```

If it works, mark it as solution.